# Can windows CDO's be RPT enabled?

Tags: ocean

Does anyone know if it is possible to RPT enable windows custom domain objects (e.g. child of a 2D window). It does not seem to work when implemented the same way as for other custom domain objects...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be possible by letting your CDOs implement the `Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Basics.ISyncable` interface.

Comment: That's what we assumed.  One example:  We have a CDO contained by IntersectionWindow.Extensions.  RPT lists only the window object, no subobjects, which is probably fine.  When copying the InterpretationWindow with RPT, only the standard Petrel DOs contained are copied.  In Petrel 2011, our ISyncableFactory is never queried about our CDO.  And yes, the CDO happens to directly implements ISyncable, but it is never queried either. In Petrel 2012, the factory is queried and a copy is created, but it never appears in the copied IntersectionWindow.

Comment: Sounds like a defect. I submitted an internal ticket and let you know when engineering investigates it.